# iOS - Document based app import file from share sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, document, ios-sharesheet

I am building a document based iOS app. When I set the "Supports Document Browser" key in the info.plist file to YES, my App is displayed with the text "Open in " underneath the icon and it is shown in the Files app in iOS. When I open the file in my app, the `url` parameter in the AppDelegate's `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` method points to the file's origin. Because the origin is not in my app's folder, I can't copy or move the file to said folder.

When I set the property in my info.plist to NO, the text underneath my app icon is "Copy to " and the url points to a file in my app's Inbox folder, where I can copy and move the file. But the app is not shown in the Files app.

Is there any way to show the app in the files app, but let opened files be copied to the Inbox folder?

Thanks in advance,
Fabian.

Answer (score 0):

If you support opening in place, you can definitely copy the file somewhere else. Just make sure you use the security-scoped URL you receive properly, and access it only under File Coordination. It would be super weird to do that, though: if the user is opening a file, not copying it, he expects the document to be edited in place. Eg. you have a document in iCloud, and open it in your app : when using a different device, you want to see the edits! If you edit a copy instead, this doesn’t work.

If you do want to edit a copy, you should definitely not appear in the Files app (except in the share sheet), because then it’s super confusing to have two copies of the document in Files.